# How to use this.container.lookup("view:viewName") in ember 2?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

In my old ember app, to display confirmation dialog, I have used `this.container.lookup('view:viewName')`

But as we know, views are removed in ember 2, how can I achieve above without using view?

I have following:

view/confirm.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'confirm'
});
```

template/confirm.hbs

```
<div id="confirmModal">
   {{!-- some text message --}}
</div>
```

controller/item.js

```
var confirmView = this.container.lookup("view:confirm").append();
// this displays above confirm template in my page
//...
confirmView.destroy();
```

Here how I can avoid using `this.container.lookup("view:confirm").append();` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a 'named outlet' in your application template and then render your modal content into it.

Links:
[Rendering templates](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.13.0/routing/rendering-a-template/)
[Rendering modals](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.12.0/cookbook/user_interface_and_interaction/using_modal_dialogs/) (warning 'slightly' out of date)

Answer (score 0):

Finally moved view to component and used it in same way :)

components/confirm.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  templateName: 'components/confirm-box'
});
```

templates/components/confirm-box.hbs

```
<div id="confirmModal">
   {{!-- some text message --}}
</div>
```

controller/item.js

```
var confirmView = this.container.lookup("component:confirm-box").append();
// this displays above confirm template in my page
//...
confirmView.destroy();
```